# JBPM pass comments from Task to Tasks

Tags: jbpm

I have two Human Tasks that I would like to pass the comments from the first task to the second task in the same workflow. The goal is to persist all comments from the start to the end of the workflow. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

jBPMs Human Tasks contains the possibility to add comments. (https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.3.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_task_details)
They getting manged by the taskservice. Which you can also access via REST-Interface.

To fetch all comments for a process Instance you need to fetch first all tasks and then all comments to this tasks.
See this doc for the endpoints: https://www.jbpm.org/api-docs/kie-server/paths.html